# What are the benefits of implementing a parent interface vs a child of that interface for your class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I'm working with a JAR provided by another team, it is an encryption JAR and using it returns an object that implements a `Closeable` instead of an `OutputStream` (`OutputStream` implements `Closeable`) but it still implements all the methods that would be necessary to be an `OutputStream` (they actually use an `OutputStream` inside their code).

`Closeable` Object:

```
public class EncryptionOutputStream implements Closeable {

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
       ...
    }
}
```

vs

`OutputStream` Object:

```
public class EncryptionOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {
       ...
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
       ...
    }
}
```

---

An `OutputStream` is what I need and what other classes of their own code require.

Code that requires an `OutputStream`:

```
public void copy(InputStream src, OutputStream dest){
    ...
{
```

I was wondering what the benefits of implementing a higher level class like that would be? It seems like implementing the child class would be beneficial not only in this case since `OutputStream`'s are so widely used, but in all cases because if a class requires an `OutputStream` as a parameter, you can't use a `Closeable`, but if a class requires a `Closeable` as a parameter you can use both a `Closeable` and `OutputStream`.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the other team what their intention was.

Comment: @vanje I was just curious if there was something obvious that I was missing, thank you for the suggestion though